# How to listen to Keydown-Events in a KineticJS-managed HTML5-Canvas?

Tags: html, events, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to add an Event Listener to a Htm5-Canvas which is managed by [Kineticjs](http://www.kineticjs.com/) (the Canvas was created via a Stage of KineticJS).

I tried out (using jQuery):

$(*selector*).keydown( function(e) {... } )

with the following Selectors:

- window (**it is working**, but it is listening to the whole Window and thereby not good)
- All Canvas-Elements $('canvas')   *<-- not working*
- The Container, where KineticJS and its Canvas are embedded  *<-- not working*
- The Container-Div of KineticJS (created by Kinetic) with $('.kineticjs-content').keydown( function() { ... } )   *<-- not working*

Only $(window) is working. After experimenting with plain Html5-Canvas i figured out, that the Canvas-Element has Built-in-Support for Keyboard-Events.
So i think, KineticJS is doing something magic around here. Wrong Selector-Usage can be excluded.

I checked every Selector with this code: console.log( $(selector).length )

Can anyone help here? Thx in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question by now?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using one of the Keyboard Plugins out there:

- http://robertwhurst.github.io/KeyboardJS/
- http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/

They work well together with KineticJS.

Answer (score 1):

If you can include javascript into it, here is the code:

```
if(keyIsPressed && keycode == somenumber){
doSomething();
}
```

Comment: this is the only real lightweight answer

Answer (score 0):

As of right now [On](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php#on) only supports mouse and touch events.

Each layer has its own [canvas](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Layer.php#getCanvas) that you can grab and attach events to.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited experience I have with this (2 days), I saw that each layer you add becomes a canvas, so if you have a reference to the topmost layer in a variable (i.e. `topmostLayer`), you can do

```
var canvas = $(topmostLayer.getContext().canvas);
```

With this in place, what [@devnull69](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030974/devnull69) suggested just works:

```
canvas.attr('tabindex', 0);
canvas.keydown(function (ev) { ... });
```

I have it in place in my application and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

see [link](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/894), you need:

```
var canvas=layer.getCanvas()._canvas;
$(canvas).attr('tabindex', 0); // increase tabindex if needed
canvas.focus();
$(canvas).keydown(function (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode); // your handler here
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to make sure that the canvas element has the focus before it can accept keyboard events. Unfotunately the .focus() method didn't work for me in Firefox, so I tried this and voilà

```
$('canvas').attr('tabindex', 0);
$('canvas').keydown(function(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
    e.preventDefault();    // to stop the key events from bubbling up
});
```

Click the canvas and it will have the focus.

Comment: In a plain Html5-Application your answer is right. But in a kineticjs-managed Canvas it will not work also.